# Do I need to start mining in order to process my own transaction in GETH?

Tags: transactions, mining

I am running my own GETH node, so that I can check status, and make transaction when possible.

I can sync with the main net and check status of contracts without start mining.

But when I send a transaction (to my GETH node using RPC), do I need to start mining in order to get my transaction processed? Or other mining nodes will eventually process it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to mine. You don't even need to run a node to send transactions. When you create a transaction from your non-mining node, it will broadcast the transaction to its peers until it gets to a mining node.

Comment: Dude, without a node, I will have to depends on services like infura RPC which is a paid service. Or is there any other better solution?

Comment: Infura RPC isn't a paid service, it's completely free to use. I'm not saying you shouldn't run your own node, as I do because it makes development much easier, but you don't need to, and you certainly don't need to be mining. You would likely never be able to mine a block anyway.